# How to prove this trig identity problem with quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, logic, proof-writing

Here is the problem:

Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x \in [0, \pi]$ such that $ \sin(nx) = \cos(x)$.

I am trying to understand how I would go about proving a multiple quantifier problem with trig identities. At first glance, I tried to disprove it, but I realized eventually that it is true basically for all $\pi/2$.

How do I prove this in a formally written proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the equality $sin(nx)=cosx$ holds for $x=\frac{\pi}{2n+2} \in [0, \pi \space]$ .

In fact we use the identity $$sin(nx)=cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-nx\right)$$

Then we want that $cos(x)=cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-nx)$ which (equating the arguments) is true for $x=\frac{\pi}{2n+2}$.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: Is there something wrong? You want to proove the existence of such x, this sketch shows one value of x in [0,pi], but there are other x in that set which satisfies the equality (I don't show that).

Comment: No you are right. Took me a minute to process haha.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$ and $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ iff $x-y=2k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Hence
$$\sin(nx) = \cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb{Z}, nx=\pi/2-x+2k\pi.$$
So, given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=\frac{\pi/2+2k\pi}{n+1}\in [0,\pi]$? Yes, take $k=0$, that is
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}.$$

P.S. Note that for $n\geq 2$, we have multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to prove a claim for all $n$, you start out by saying something like, "let $n$ be arbitrary". Then you pick an $x$, in terms of $n$, and show that the claim is true for that $x$.

That should do it, but it won't be $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $n$. It certainly works if $n$ is even. For odd $n$, you'll need to think of some other $x$.